# iso-charts Line Chart right axis min and max values not set properly

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-charts

After migrating to Swift 3, my line chart is displayed with strange values in the y-axis. I am not sure if it is the range or the dataset that has the problem. But I checked and the y values seem to be correct. 
The chart itself is also displayed as a blue rectangle instead of a line chart (I am assuming because of the wrong y values)
Would any one have an idea what could be wrong by looking at this chart?

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5VBQ.png)

**Update:**
I was able to pinpoint the problem to the right axis axisMinimum and axisMaximum that do not get set properly. When I use the same code for the left axis, it works perfectly.

here is the code for setting up:

```
class func newLineChartViewWithXValsAndDataSets(frame: CGRect, xVals: [String], dataSets: [SVLineChartDataSet]?, maximum: ChartDataEntry?, minimum: ChartDataEntry?) -> LineChartView {
    let lineChartView = LineChartView(frame: frame)
    let chartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    let margin: CGFloat = 6
    lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    lineChartView.dragEnabled = false
    lineChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    lineChartView.drawBordersEnabled = false
    lineChartView.legend.textColor = UIColor.sharevilleLightGrey

    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.sharevilleLightGrey
    lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.sharevilleTouchGrey
    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = LineChartDateFormatter(dates: xVals)
    lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(3, force: true)

    lineChartView.leftAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.sharevilleTouchGrey
    //lineChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    //lineChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    lineChartView.leftAxis.spaceTop = margin
    lineChartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = margin
    lineChartView.leftAxis.resetCustomAxisMax()
    lineChartView.leftAxis.resetCustomAxisMin()

    lineChartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.sharevilleDarkGrey
    lineChartView.rightAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.sharevilleTouchGrey
    lineChartView.rightAxis.gridColor = UIColor.sharevilleTouchGrey
    lineChartView.rightAxis.labelPosition = .insideChart
    lineChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    lineChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    lineChartView.rightAxis.spaceTop = margin
    lineChartView.rightAxis.spaceBottom = margin


    // if we have no maximum and minimumvalue return the linechart directly
    guard let maximum = maximum, let minimum = minimum else {
        return lineChartView
    }

    //let absMinMax = abs(maximum.y - minimum.y)
    //let visibleYRangeMaxium = max(absMinMax,1) * 1.2
   // print("visibile Y Range")
   // print(visibleYRangeMaxium)

    //lineChartView.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(visibleYRangeMaxium, axis: YAxis.AxisDependency.left)

    lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum =  minimum.y
    lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum =  maximum.y
    //lineChartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum =  minimum.y
    //lineChartView.rightAxis.axisMaximum =  maximum.y


    lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1, easingOption: .easeInCubic)

    print("LinChartView.data= ", lineChartView.data)
    lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
    lineChartView.backgroundColor = .white


    if let dataSets = dataSets {
        for dataSet in dataSets {

            if dataSet.isLineChartViewHighLowEnabled {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.drawLineChartValueView(lineChartView, dataEntry: maximum)
                    self.drawLineChartValueView(lineChartView, dataEntry: minimum)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    lineChartView.data = chartData

    return lineChartView
}
```

Comment: which value is wrong in this chat ? what does it suppose to display instead ?

Comment: The right axis values are not the same as what I see on debugging in my dataset. Also the chart range should be the max and min values (which are displayed correctly here)

Comment: Can you post your code setting up the chart? We can probably help see where you converted to Swift 3 wrongly

Comment: @AdityaGarg please check the update. I was able to narrow down the problem but I have no idea what I need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you set your data set `axisDependency` to right axis.

Comment: That was exactly it!